# How to shuffle posts in two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was working on a post system..
So, I have to show posts by friends of the user and the groups in which user has participated..
Here is my code to show posts..

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uploader_id=:friend_id ORDER BY id DESC";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(
     ":friend_id" => $friend_id
  ));
  $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $name = $row['name'];
      echo "POST BY $name";
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM group_posts WHERE id=:member_group ORDER BY id DESC";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(
     ":member_group" => $group_id
  ));
  $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $name = $row['name'];
     echo "POST BY $name";
  }
?>
```

Now, I want all these posts to be shuffled in a way that all the posts of the post table and group_posts table are shown in the descending order.

UPDATE

I edited my code to this..
I figured out that first I'll have to code this before coding my post system..

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_one=:me OR user_two=:me2 UNION SELECT * FROM group_members WHERE member_id=:me3";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(
      ":me" => $my_id,
      ":me2" => $my_id,
      ":me3" => $my_id
  ));
  $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $user_one = $row['user_one'];
     $user_two = $row['user_two'];
     $group_id = $row['group_id'];
     if ($user_one == $my_id) {
         $friend_id = $user_two;
     } else {
         $friend_id = $user_one;
     }
     echo $friend_id . "<BR>" . $group_id;
  }
?>
```

Now, here's the problem..
This is successfully printing the $friend_id but, it shows an undefined index 'group_id' while printing $group_id.
I have checked all the fields are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using just one query with `UNION`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT name, id FROM posts WHERE uploader_id=:friend_id
  UNION
  SELECT name, id FROM group_posts WHERE id=:member_group
) p
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Note, your inner queries must return the **same** number of columns in the same order (and I think with the same name/alias, too).

Comment: @user3436939, are all of the columns in table `friends` also present in table `group_posts` and vice versa? If not, you can't do a `SELECT *`. You need to restrict the two queries separated by the `UNION` so they `SELECT` the _same_ data in the same order.